# A strcpy gcc inline assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Can anybody tell me what work these two variables `int rsrc, rdst;` do? OR explain the following code to me statement by statement?

```
static inline char * asm_strcpy(char *dst, char *src) {
    int rsrc, rdst;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "1: \tlodsb\n\t;"
        "stosb\n\t;"
        "testb %%al,%%al\n\t;"
        "jne 1b;"
        : "=&S" (rsrc), "=&D" (rdst)
        : "0" (src),"1" (dst) 
        );
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` copies characters from one string to another. src = source, dst = destination, r = register (?)

Comment: `=` and `&` are [constraint modifiers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers). `S` is `si` register and `D` is `di` register on Intel 386. These two are [machine-dependent constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints).

Comment: BTW - the "&" constraints for 'early-clobber outputs' do nothing here, since you've aliased these with the inputs "0", "1" anyway. You could omit the inputs, and replace the outputs with: "+S" (src), "+D" (dst). "%eax" must be added to the clobber list, and it would be more technically correct to add "memory" to the clobber list also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsrc` and `rdst` are used as placeholder variables and later the compiler is instructed to optimize them in registers, using exactly `SI` and `DI`. The same is happening with `src` and `dst` but they are used as input for the assembly code, while `rsrc` and `rdst` are its discarded output.

the assembly code is quite trivial:

```
1:
  lodsb ; loads byte at *SI to register AL, increments SI
  stosb ; stores byte at *DI from register AL, increments DI
  testb AL,AL ; sets flags based on value in AL
  jne 1: ; repeat if AL is non zero
```

for all this to operate correctly the direction flag should be clear; there is no rule of thumb because it may depend on calling convention or may be freely modified throughout the program

if the above code should be made DF agnostic, the following should wrap it:

```
PUSHF
CLD
...
POPF
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now and wish other could learn from this typical example.

Comment: can you help me to see this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642383/substring-c-inline-assembly-code