# substring -- c inline assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I write a code that get substring of a string with gcc inline assembly. but always get problem when I want to get the substring whose length is 8. here is the code

```
static inline char * asm_sub_str(char *dest, char *src, int s_idx, int edix)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("cld\n\t"
                         "rep\n\t"
                         "movsb"
                         :
                         :"S"(src + s_idx), "D"(dest), "c"(edix - s_idx + 1)
                         );
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char my_string[STRINGSIZE] = "abc defghij";
    char asm_my_sub_string[STRINGSIZE];

    int sidx,eidx;

    sidx = 0;
    eidx = 5;
    char *d1 = asm_sub_str(asm_my_sub_string, my_string, sidx, eidx);
    printf("d1[%d-%d]: %s\n",sidx, eidx, d1);

    sidx = 0;
    eidx = 7;
    d1 = asm_sub_str(asm_my_sub_string, my_string, sidx, eidx);
    printf("d1[%d-%d]: %s\n",sidx, eidx, d1);

    sidx = 0;
    eidx = 9;
    d1 = asm_sub_str(asm_my_sub_string, my_string, sidx, eidx);
    printf("d1[%d-%d]: %s\n",sidx, eidx, d1);

}
```

here is the output

```
d1[0-5]: abc de
d1[0-7]: abc defg?
d1[0-9]: abc defghi
```

any idea?????

Thanks for reply. Here is the c code of substring and I forgot to null terminate the string. Thank cactus and bbonev! Wish someone else can learn from this thread.

```
static inline char * sub_str(char *dest, char *src, int s_idx, int edix)
{
    int length = edix - s_idx + 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *(dest + i) = *(src + s_idx + i);
    }
    *(dest + length) = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Where's it not working..? If anything I'd assume it's because you're not null-terminating the strings correctly, which means it's somewhat lucky that it works at all.

Comment: thank you so much. But it's interesting that problem only happen when eidx-sidx = 8, which means the desired substring's length is 8. Otherwise it works lucky. I still cannot figure this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose its not working because the assembly code does not 0 terminate the result buffer.

I would always prefer the substring semantics with starting position and count, instead of two positions. People think little easier in such terms.

There is no need to return any value from this function.

```
static inline void asm_sub_str(char *dest, char *src, int s_idx, int count)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("cld\n"
                         "rep\n"
                         "movsb\n"
                         "xor %%al,%%al\n"
                         "stosb\n"
                         :
                         :"S"(src + s_idx), "D"(dest), "c"(count)
                         );
}
```

EDIT: Note that this implementation is quite suboptimal although written in assembly. For a particular architecture memory alignment and word size are important for speed and probably the best way to do the copy is by aligned machine size words. First copy up to word size-1 bytes one by one, then copy the big part of the string in words and finally finish the last up to word size-1 bytes.

I take the question as an excersize in inline assembly and passing parameters, not as the best way to copy strings. With modern C compilers its expected that with -O2 faster code will be generated.

Comment: This is very wrong. ESI/RSI, EDI/RSI, and ECX/RCX are actually all clobbered (modified) by `movsb`. They need to be input and output type constraints. You've also clobbered EAX/RAX as well in the template but didn't tell GCC. If you modify something inside the assembly template you need to make sure the compiler knows. With optimizations on this will likely break pretty badly. As well you would at a minimum need a `memory` clobber (there is an alternative way but not as easy) to make sure `src` and `dest` are realized into memory before the inline template is called.